# val_loss in keras is doing average or sum?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training an ANN using Keras. The training itself is being done by the commands:

```
history=model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=32,epochs=500,verbose=1,validation_split = 0.2 ) #train on the noise (not moshe)
fit=model.predict(x_test)
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
```

My question is whether val_loss takes the summary of the error or the average one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your loss function. Generally the losses will be the mean of the loss for each sample, for example a super common loss like `mean_squared_error`:

```
def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

It clearly takes the mean (average) of all the losses.

The thing is there isn't a definite answer because you can always pass in a custom loss function that takes the sum:

```
def sum_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

TLDR: Generally yes, but check the source for each loss function you use to be sure. You can find source of `keras`'s builtin losses [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py).